# Text in a UITableView that's not contained in a cell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

How do you add non-cell text to a `UITableView`? For example, on iPhone, in Settings > Sounds there is the text "The volume of the ringer and alerts can be adjusted using... etc". This text is not a cell or section title, is in a different font than section titles and does not appear in a cell itself. So how do you add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible they are using a custom view as a footer.  In the [`UITableViewDelegate` Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForFooterInSection%3a) there is the method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

You could create a custom view that has no background, and just contains the label with your text in it for that particular section.